# ClassicURLConnection exc_bad_access error. iOS

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, afnetworking-2

I'm using **AFNetworking (2.2.4)** for my app.
**When i try to do pull to refresh in several screens in one time app crashes.** Here stack trace:

Always crash in thread:

```
Thread 17, Queue : ClassicURLConnection
```

Stack:

```
#0  0x2ebc930a in CFDictionaryContainsKey ()
#1  0x2e90ab58 in HTTPHeaderDict::containsKey(HTTPHeaderKeyMixedValue const&) const ()
#2  0x2e8cb76a in HTTPMessage::hasHeaderField(CFNetworkCanonicalStringConstant) const ()
#3  0x2e88012e in HTTPProtocol::_createMutableCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*) ()
#4  0x2e88004c in HTTPProtocol::_createCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*) ()
#5  0x2e87f706 in URLConnectionClient::_internalEvent_WillSendRequest() ()
#6  0x2e8bf80e in ___ZN20ClassicURLConnection5startEv_block_invoke ()
#7  0x2e8c06d2 in ___ZN20ClassicURLConnection16_withClientAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP15ClientInterfaceE_block_invoke ()
#8  0x2e8e825c in ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData19_withWorkQueueAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#9  0x2e91b49a in ___ZNK18QCoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#10 0x39905d52 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#11 0x3990acbc in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#12 0x39907c6e in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#13 0x3990b5f0 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#14 0x3990b8dc in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#15 0x39a36c16 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

And again:

```
Thread 4, Queue : ClassicURLConnection
```

Stack:

```
#0  0x3941ccc0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x2ec89836 in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
#2  0x2ec88136 in ___forwarding___ ()
#3  0x2ebd7098 in _CF_forwarding_prep_0 ()
#4  0x2ebc9384 in CFDictionaryContainsKey ()
#5  0x2e90ab58 in HTTPHeaderDict::containsKey(HTTPHeaderKeyMixedValue const&) const ()
#6  0x2e8cb76a in HTTPMessage::hasHeaderField(CFNetworkCanonicalStringConstant) const ()
#7  0x2e88012e in HTTPProtocol::_createMutableCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*,     _CFURLRequest const*, void const*) ()
#8  0x2e88004c in HTTPProtocol::_createCanonicalRequest(__CFAllocator const*, _CFURLRequest const*, void const*) ()
#9  0x2e87f706 in URLConnectionClient::_internalEvent_WillSendRequest() ()
#10 0x2e8bf80e in ___ZN20ClassicURLConnection5startEv_block_invoke ()
#11 0x2e8c06d2 in ___ZN20ClassicURLConnection16_withClientAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP15ClientInterfaceE_block_invoke ()
#12 0x2e8e825c in ___ZNK25URLConnectionInstanceData19_withWorkQueueAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#13 0x2e91b49a in ___ZNK18QCoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke ()
#14 0x39905d52 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#15 0x3990acbc in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#16 0x39907c6e in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#17 0x3990b5f0 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#18 0x3990b8dc in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#19 0x39a36c16 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

//

```
-[__NSCFString containsKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1567ed20
```

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE**

Maybe this code?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = (NSMutableURLRequest *)op.request;

if ([request isKindOfClass: [NSMutableURLRequest class]])
{
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    request.timeoutInterval = kRequestTimeout;

    [request setValue:[self.class userAgentString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
}

[op start];
```

Comment: Looks like a NSDictionay object is getting converted into NSString object down the line somewhere. Can't tell you for sure without seeing some of the code invoking this error

Comment: Hi, @PanayotPanayotov. How can i get this code? exc_bad_acceess...

Comment: UserAgent will be set for you automaticaly. Remove this line of code and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line of code

```
[request setValue:[self.class userAgentString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

User agent will be set for you automatically. Leave this alone unless you like to set this value to something else like

```
[request setValue:@"My iOS app" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I set headers like this: [_operationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"header"];